# Reading the content of robots.txt in Python and printing it

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, urllib2, robots.txt

I want to check if a given website contains robot.txt, read all the content of that file and print it. Maybe also add the content to a dictionary would be very good.

I've tried playing with the [`robotparser` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/robotparser.html) but can't figure out how to do it.

I would like to use only modules that come with the standard Python 2.7 package.

I did as @Stefano Sanfilippo suggested:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
```

returned

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
ImportError: No module named request
```

So I tried:

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import Request
from urllib2 import urlopen
with urlopen("https://www.google.com/robots.txt") as stream:
    print(stream.read().decode("utf-8"))
```

but got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "", line 1, in 
    with urlopen("https://www.google.com/robots.txt") as stream:
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute '**exit**'

From [bugs.python.org](http://bugs.python.org/issue12955) it seems that's something not supported in 2.7 version.
As a matter of fact the code works fine with Python 3
Any idea how to work this around?

Comment: You don't need to know anything about the structure of the site to know where `robots.txt` has to be. It's always at `whatever.site.name/robots.txt`.

Comment: @jonsharpe I reworded the question. Is it sufficient narrow now? Question is solved but I was wondering if the status "on hold" could be removed.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `robots.txt` is just a file, download and print it!

Python 3:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen("https://www.google.com/robots.txt") as stream:
    print(stream.read().decode("utf-8"))
```

Python 2:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from contextlib import closing

with closing(urlopen("https://www.google.com/robots.txt")) as stream:
    print stream.read()
```

Note that the path is always `/robots.txt`.

If you need to put content in a dictionary, `.split(":")` and `.strip()` are your friends:

Comment: Your code works with Python 3 but not with Python 2.7
Can you suggest me how to make it work with Python 2.7?

Comment: See the edit. However, you should _really_ be using Python 3, unless you have a specific reason to stick with Python 2. Python 2 is legacy, and it's not me to say it, [it's official](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3).

Comment: Thanks @Stefano Sanfilippo I'll check the tool 2to3 to convert my code. I don't know why I had the impression that using the 2.7 version was still a good idea.